# How do I implement a string protocol for an array of custom type in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a custom type that maps to a custom Postgres type. The below code is the relevant code for the same

```
@typedoc """
Slot is composed of start time and end time.
"""

@type t :: %Slot{start_time: Time.t(), end_time: Time.t()}

@enforce_keys [:start_time, :end_time]
defstruct start_time: nil, end_time: nil

def new(start_time, end_time) when is_binary(start_time) and is_binary(end_time) do
 with {:ok, start_time} <- Time.from_iso8601(start_time),
      {:ok, end_time} <- Time.from_iso8601(end_time),
      {:ok, _} <- validate_start_time_before_end_time(start_time, end_time) do
   %Slot{start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time}
 else
   {:error, :invalid_slot} ->
     {:error, {ArgumentError, "start time should be before end time"}}

   {:error, :invalid_format} ->
     {:error, {ArgumentError, "start time or end time not valid time"}}
 end
end

def new(start_time, end_time) do
 %Slot{start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time}
end

defp validate_start_time_before_end_time(start_time, end_time) do
 if Time.compare(start_time, end_time) != :lt do
   {:error, :invalid_slot}
 else
   {:ok, nil}
 end
end
```

What I would like to have is a `protocol` `String.Chars` implemented for an array of such custom types. The documentation is not very clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is unclear in the documentation, but [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is [OSS](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.3/lib/elixir/lib/string/chars.ex#L3).

```rb
defimpl String.Chars, for: Slot do
  def to_string(slot) do
    "start_time: #{slot.start_time}, end_time: #{slot.end_time}"
  end
end
```

Usually, we use custom implementation for `Inspect`, not for `String.Chars`, though.

---

*Sidenote:* there is no *array* in *Elixir* core.

Comment: Hey I have done this implementation. I wanted one with array/list of slots. Seems like its not possible. Thanks :)

Comment: a) array and list are not interchangeable synonyms; we have only linked lists in [tag:elixir] core, b) to print out lists, or other terms, we implement `Inspect` not `String.Chars` as I have mentioned above.